# Use F# in Azure Functions

Tags: azure, f#, azure-functions

What is the best way to use F# in Azure Functions at the moment? I want my function to have both input and output bindings (e.g. to queues or event hubs)

What I found so far:

- [Queue triggered FSX](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/tree/master/sample/QueueTrigger-FSharp) - but it has no output bindings and [is reported to be slow](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f5a21e73-a62b-4f11-a33a-aaf49c30dbdf/slow-startup-for-fsx-function-call?forum=AzureFunctions)
- Compile F# code to exe file and [run Function as external executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36436917/execute-pre-compiled-net-code-as-azure-function) - but again the output queue binding isn't clear to me, I guess the exe file would have to send the item explicitly

Is there a way to take an F# function with inputs and output and host it as a Azure Function directly? Something similar to C# `Run` method?

Ideally, inputs and outputs should be strongly typed: an object, record or discriminated union.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The templates are only meant to be *starting points* - you can add additional input/output bindings to them easily in the portal "Integrate" tab. For example, if you add a new Blob output named `result` and bound to blob path `"test-output/%rand-guid%"`, you can write script like the below that writes a blob:

```
open System
open System.IO

let inputPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("input")
let input = File.ReadAllText(inputPath)
let message = sprintf "F# script processed queue message '%s'" input
System.Console.Out.WriteLine(message)

let resultPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("result")
File.WriteAllText(resultPath, input);
```

Regarding more strongly typed "first class" support for F#, as I mentioned in the forum post you linked to, we're working on it :) For now, F# is in the bucket with all the other out of proc script types, where the communication mechanism in and out of the binding pipeline is via **environment variables** as you can see above.

Answer (score 6):

Now F# is native!

> Thanks to the excellent work by the F# team including Don Syme and Tomas Petricek, we're happy to announce we finally support F# in a first-class fashion in Azure Functions.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2016/09/01/azure-functions-0-5-release-august-portal-update/