# Access Nuget Packages hosted in private Nuget server in Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions

How can I access nuget packages hosted in private nuget server in Azure Functions?. Is there any way I can specify my private nuget server info?

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Krishh,

This is possible using a `nuget.config` file as you normally would:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="MyPrivateFeed" value="http://myhost/myfeed" />
    ... other feeds ...
  </packageSources>
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
  </activePackageSource>
</configuration>
```

Using Kudu, or another deployment method outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36411536/how-can-i-use-nuget-packages-in-my-azure-functions), copy that file to either the function folder or `wwwroot` (that would apply to all functions) and your config will be used.

Comment: Krishh, the latest deployment contains this update. Since there was a minor version bump with this deployment, the changes will not be automatically applied to existing Function Apps, so you may need to change your FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION app setting to ~0.2 (you can find the application settings under Function app settins > Go to app service settings > Application Settings)

Comment: per https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/get-started/nuget/auth#net-core using a private NuGet feed looks to be impossible (requires local machine changes?), or at least unwise (storing a PAT in plaintext). Is this something that will get better support soon?

Comment: I would also like to know the answer to Joe's question. We have a private NuGet feed hosted by VSTS, and I would like to use packages from that in an Azure Function App, but I want (need) to do it securely (not storing keys in source control) and in a scaleable/manageable way (not needing to make changes manually in every deployment). Can this be accomplished?

Comment: @FabioCavalcante any update on the deployment of this?

Comment: @FabioCavalcante any updates on this? I tried what's mentioned but can't get it to work

Comment: @RPM1984 the deployment comment reflected a pre-release state. This should work on the current runtime as-is. What issues are you seeing?

Comment: @FabioCavalcante i got it working. _None_ of my Nuget packages were working. I had an issue in my NuGet.config where i was referencing SeriLog 2.4.0.0, needed to be 2.4.0. When i updated that, it then reinstalled _all_ the packages, including my private ones. Thanks!

Comment: I just tried creating nuget.config in the site/wwwroot, and that hasn't worked :(

Answer (score 3):

There are several posts related to your question if we assume that your private nuget package can be deployed as a simple .Net library:

- [Execute pre-compiled .NET code as Azure Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36436917/execute-pre-compiled-net-code-as-azure-function)
- [How do you include references to external assemblies in Azure Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36437582/how-do-you-include-references-to-external-assemblies-in-azure-functions)
- [How do I use external assemblies with Microsoft Azure Function Apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36559509/how-do-i-use-external-assemblies-with-microsoft-azure-function-apps)
- [How to put the entry point of an Azure Function inside a .NET DLL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577584/how-to-put-the-entry-point-of-an-azure-function-inside-a-net-dll)

Comment: I was wondering if there was anyway when restoring nuget packages we could specify the private nuget server info?. @Thomas

Comment: If your server is accessible, it could be. ask a new quesiotn to see if there is any option to specify the nuget source packages