# How do I provide private NuGet feed credentials to an Azure Function?

Tags: azure, nuget, nuget-package, azure-functions

I am trying to create an Azure function which has dependencies on NuGet packages hosted in a private NuGet feed.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36731883/3213157) describes using a `nuget.config` file which is uploaded to the app service which hosts the function - my `nuget.config`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="MyPrivateFeed" value="https://<url to feed>" />
  </packageSources>
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
  </activePackageSource>
</configuration>
```

My function is using this config file as expected, but it doesn't have the credentials it needs. The Azure function portal shows the following:

```
2016-10-04T09:00:55.442 Starting NuGet restore
2016-10-04T09:00:56.926 Restoring packages for D:\home\site\wwwroot\HttpTriggerSqlDb\project.json...
2016-10-04T09:00:58.267 Please provide credentials for: https://<url to feed>
2016-10-04T09:00:58.515 Unable to load the service index for source https://<url to feed>.
2016-10-04T09:00:58.515 Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
```

How do I provide credentials for the private feed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to set up your credentials directly in the nuget config file: https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/schema/nuget.config-file.md#packagesourcecredentials.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What should the feed name be? I don't have it defined in the config file. Could you elaborate your answer to show how it should look?

Comment: I believe the feed name is the 'key' in your source -- so above it would be `MyPrivateFeed`.