# Azure Functions dll referencing

Tags: azure, azure-functions

How can I use the "#r" preprocessor directive to reference dlls from another container?

Common #r usage will only search for dlls inside the container on my function app resource group.

Answer (score 1):

I think your goal could be achieved in a better way.

If you want to find your Azure Files account, go to `<functionapp>.azurewebsites.net/Env`and look for `APPSETTING_WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING` and `APPSETTING_WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE`.

To access the reference across functions, create a nuget package for your dll and create a `project.json` for each function ([How can I use NuGet packages in my Azure Functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36411536/how-can-i-use-nuget-packages-in-my-azure-functions?rq=1) / [Access Nuget Packages hosted in private Nuget server in Azure Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36707613/access-nuget-packages-hosted-in-private-nuget-server-in-azure-functions/36731883#36731883))

Using precompiled functions is another good option for managing your references by moving development locally & using normal web app deployment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/Precompiled-functions and https://aka.ms/precompiled-functions.

Answer (score 0):

As was said, It's better you use ProGet as an universal Package Manager. After this ProGet Environment had been installed and configured with your external .dlls, You'll able to configure all your Azure Functions to look for their dependencies in this ProGet Package manager.