# Using BrokeredMessage with ServiceBus Queue Trigger in Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I've created an [Azure Function](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-overview/) that is triggered any time a new message is added to an Azure ServiceBus queue.
With this code it works fine:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
#load "..\shared\person.csx"

using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

public static void Run(string message, TraceWriter log)
{
    var person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(message, 
            new JsonSerializerSettings() {ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()});
    log.Verbose($"From DeserializeObject: {person.FirstName} {person.LastName}");
}
```

I've seen that I can also bind the message to a POCO like that:

```
public static void Run(Person message, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Verbose($"From DeserializeObject: {message.FirstName} {message.LastName}");
}
```

Now I would like to bind the message to a `BrokeredMessage` because I need to have access to the properties of the message.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Edit** New SDK supports the servicebus sdk using `#r directive`

```
#r "Microsoft.ServiceBus"
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;

public static void Run(BrokeredMessage msg, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {msg}");
}
```

**Old version**

Only two steps:

I've create a `project.json` file to add a reference to the `WindowsAzure.ServiceBus` Nuget package (see [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36411536/how-can-i-use-nuget-packages-in-my-azure-functions)):

```
{
    "frameworks": {
        "net46":{
            "dependencies": {
                "WindowsAzure.ServiceBus": "2.7.6"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've added a reference to the brokered message:

```
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;

public static void Run(BrokeredMessage  message, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Verbose("Function has been triggered !!!");
}
```

Comment: Yes, it took me some time to figure out how to bind to a brokeremessage. Just sharing the information ^^

Answer (score 2):

I tried Thomas' solution and it seems that this does not work anymore.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#referencing-external-assemblies) states:

> In addition, the following assemblies are special cased and may be referenced by simplename (e.g. #r "AssemblyName"):
>
> - ...
> - Microsoft.ServiceBus

So without touching the project.json file the following works:

```
#r "Microsoft.ServiceBus"

using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;

public static void Run(BrokeredMessage msg, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {msg}");
}
```