# Intercept Azure Function Host Shutdown: Flush Application Insights TelemetryClient

Tags: c#, azure-webjobs, azure-application-insights, azure-webjobssdk, azure-functions

I am playing a little bit with Azure Function: Mostly I try to migrate an existing webjob to Azure Functions and now it is time for me to integrate Application Insights in one of my function.

So basically I only need one instance of the `TelemetryClient` but this assumes that I am able to flush the in-memory buffer when the application stops.

I've used a TimerTrigger but it was just for testing purpose.

I've referenced the [Microsoft.ApplicationInsights](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights/) nuget package ([from this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36411536/how-can-i-use-nuget-packages-in-my-azure-functions)) and my `run.csx` file looks like that:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;

public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
{
    MyTimerJob.TelemetryClient.TrackEvent("AzureFunctionTriggered");
    log.Verbose($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
}    

public static class MyTimerJob
{
    public static readonly TelemetryClient TelemetryClient;

    static MyTimerJob(){
        TelemetryClient = new TelemetryClient()
            { InstrumentationKey = "MyInstrumentationKey" };

        // When it shutdowns, we flush the telemty client.
        new WebJobsShutdownWatcher().Token.Register(() =>
        {
            TelemetryClient.TrackEvent("TelemetryClientFlush");
            TelemetryClient.Flush();
        });
    }
}
```

This implementation is a bit tricky...

- I have a static `TelemetryClient` to ensure that I am going to reuse the same instance.
- I tried using the `WebJobsShutdownWatcher` to detect when the host is stopping so that I can flush the TelemetryClient.

To simulate the application shutdown, I've created a `"test"` app setting in the underlying web app and I modify it when I want the host to restart:

[image: Azure Function - Application terminated log]

Unfortunately this does not work... I did not see any event with name `"TelemetryClientFlush"` from the app insights dashboard:

[image: Microsoft Application Insights - Custom Events dashboard]

So I am now wondering if there is any way to intercept when the azure function host is stopping ?

Comment: Can you please add $log statement to your shutdown callback to confirm that code runs at all. Looking at WebJobsShutdownWatcher source, there are a couple of conditions that need to be followed for shutdown callback to run: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host/WebjobsShutdownWatcher.cs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to what Mathew described, you may want to play around with the cancellation token we'll pass if requested.

If  you add a `CancellationToken` type argument to your function, we'll pass in a token that will  be signaled when the host shuts down under normal circumstances. Using that may get you *close* to what you need:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;

public static readonly TelemetryClient TelemetryClient = new  TelemetryClient(){ InstrumentationKey = "MyInstrumentationKey" };
public static bool first = true;
public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log, CancellationToken token)
{
    if(first){
        token.Register(() =>
        {
            TelemetryClient.TrackEvent("TelemetryClientFlush");
            TelemetryClient.Flush();
        });
        first = false;
    }

    TelemetryClient.TrackEvent("AzureFunctionTriggered");
    log.Verbose($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
}
```

Comment: So that I can store the cancellation token and register an action that will be executed when the host shut down ?

Comment: Yes, you'd need to register the action if not registered yet (i.e. the first time your function is called). That action will be called when/if the token is signaled.

Comment: Fabio, rather than editing my question or post a new answer, I've edited your answer with the sample code I've used (It could be usefull for people not familiar with the webjob sdk). It works great !!! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

While Azure Functions does run on top of the WebJobs SDK, it does not run under the traditional [Kudu WebJobs](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Web-jobs) infrastructure. The `WebJobsShutdownWatcher` actually relies on functionality of the Kudu host, specifically the sentinel file indicated by `WEBJOBS_SHUTDOWN_FILE`. Basically when the Kudu host is shutting down it touches this file which the watcher is monitoring. Since no such file is being touched, your code is not being triggered.

We could make changes to allow the watcher to work as is, or we might instead introduce a new pattern for Functions. I've logged an issue in our repo [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/281) tracking this suggestion. I think the scenario is important and we'll give it some thought.