# F# NuGet packages in Azure Functions

Tags: f#, nuget, azure-functions

Using csx scripts in Azure Functions [I can use the `Project.json`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36411536/how-can-i-use-nuget-packages-in-my-azure-functions) file to install nuget packages, but when I'm using fsx scripts the packages aren't installed (the log console never shows the `Starting NuGet restore` message). The only way I found is installing locally and uploading the dependencies. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the current execution model for F# in Azure functions does not support project.json. There is a [work in progress PR to improve F# support](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/pull/279) that will enable this.

For now, I think there are two options:

- Install the packages locally and upload them to Azure (as you are doing)
- If you're deploying via git, then I think the deployment lets you run deployment script (in the same way in which Azure WebSites let you run a deployment script).

I have not tested the second approach with Azure functions, but I think it *could* work. For example, see the [F# Snippets' deployment script](https://github.com/fssnippets/fssnip-website/blob/master/.deployment) which calls a [build script](https://github.com/fssnippets/fssnip-website/blob/master/build.cmd) that starts by [using Paket](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/) to restore dependencies. This way, you need just `paket.bootstrapper.exe` and `paket.dependencies` with `paket.lock` to specify your NuGet dependencies.