# How do you use custom NuGet feeds with Azure Functions?

Tags: azure-functions

I know you can create a `project.json` file to add NuGet packages to your functions, but how can I specify what feed I want them pulled from?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use NuGet packages in my Azure Functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36411536/how-can-i-use-nuget-packages-in-my-azure-functions)

Comment: The answer given there does not discuss additional nuget feeds at all, just how to use the `project.json` file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Azure functions supports the standard nuget.config approach to setup custom sources. 
You can place a nuget.config file with your custom sources either in your function folder or in the Function App root (where it will be used for all functions)

You can find more information about the file format and specifying custom sources here: https://docs.nuget.org/consume/nuget-config-file#package-sources

Comment: Do I have to do anything special when referencing a package from a private nuget feed in my project.json file? Every example I can find is referencing a package from nuget.org

Comment: how does this work with feeds you need to authenticate to?