# Can not reference GeoSpatial type Point in Azure functions

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions

I want to store location information in DocumentDB, hence using the Point type from DocumentDB. I have a class LocationInfo to map data from the incoming post request.

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using Newtonsoft.Json; 
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Spatial;

public class LocationInfo
{    
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "deviceId")]
    public string DeviceId {get; set;}

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "location")]
    public Point Location {get; set;}

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "activityId")]
    public string ActivityId {get; set;}

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "type")]
    public string Type {get; set;}

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "dateTime")]
    public DateTime DateTime {get; set;}
}
```

My function isn't compiling and I am getting the error below.

```
error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Documents' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Azure' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Point' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

How do I reference `using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Spatial;` in an Azure Function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add the Document DB nuget package to your function, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36411537/5915331

> 1. In the function's develop section, click on view files
> 2. Click on the option to create a file (you can also click on the option to upload a file if you have a previously created project.json file on your machine
> 3. Name the file project.json and define your package references (you can use the example above as a template).

Comment: I did think about this but thought project.json was dumped so didn't bother. Anyway its sorted, Thanks.