# The type or namespace name 'SendGridClient' could not be found in Azure function

Tags: c#, azure, sendgrid, azure-functions

I want to send email using SendGrid using Azure function. I am using c# code to do it. Below is my sample code. When I compile the code, I am getting below error,

```
#r "System.Configuration"
#r "System.Data"
#r "SendGrid"

using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Configuration;
using SendGrid;
using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;

public static async Task < HttpResponseMessage > Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log) {

         var client = new SendGridClient(sendgridApiKey);
         var msg = new SendGridMessage()
         {
             From = new EmailAddress("sample@gmail.com", "DX Team"),
             Subject = "Hello World from the SendGrid CSharp SDK!",
             PlainTextContent = "Hello, Email!",
             HtmlContent = "<strong>Hello, Email using HTML!</strong>"
         };
         var recipients = new List<EmailAddress>
         {
             new EmailAddress("test@gmail.com", "John"),
             new EmailAddress("sa@gmail.com", "Sam")
         };
        msg.AddTo(recipients);
         msg.SetFooterSetting(
                      true,
                      "Some Footer HTML",
                      "<strong>Some Footer Text</strong>");
        var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
}
```

Error:-

```
The type or namespace name 'SendGridClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
The type or namespace name 'SendGridMessage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
The type or namespace name 'EmailAddress' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
The type or namespace name 'EmailAddress' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
The type or namespace name 'EmailAddress' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
The type or namespace name 'EmailAddress' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
 Compilation failed.
```

My references is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/sendgrid-dotnet-how-to-send-email)

How do I solve this?

Comment: This might be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36411536/how-can-i-use-nuget-packages-in-my-azure-functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I checked this issue, you could refer to the following steps to install [SendGrid](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sendgrid/) package via azure portal as follows:

[image]

[image]

**Note:** Since you have multiple recipients, you need to use `msg.AddTos(recipients)`.

Additionally, as J. Steen commented that you could refer to [How can I use NuGet packages in my Azure Functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36411536/how-can-i-use-nuget-packages-in-my-azure-functions)
 for more details. Moreover, you could refer to [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/03/16/publishing-a-net-class-library-as-a-function-app/) for more details about how to deploy pre-compiled assemblies to azure functions.

Comment: Which method is better between above method and this one - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-sendgrid

Comment: Per my understanding, bindings is a simple way for us, e.g we do not need to init the `SendGridClient` instance or execute the sendEmail operation by yourself. I would prefer choosing init the SendGridClient by myself and send the email, since it would be more flexible.

Comment: Ok Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the NuGet package reference. To add it, create a `project.json` file of the following content:

```json
{
  "frameworks": {
    "net46":{
      "dependencies": {
        "Sendgrid": "9.5.0"
      }
    }
   }
}
```

As a side note, I recommend you trying to use [SendGrid output binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-sendgrid) instead of sending the mail with custom code. You'll basically have and output parameter of type `Mail`, and the rest will be done by the binding.

Comment: After creating project.json with above content. how should I use it in my function? It will be useful If you provide me steps

Answer (score 0):

For runtime version 3, I have created a function.proj file like this:

```
  <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
       <PackageReference Include="SendGrid" Version="9.12.6" />
   </ItemGroup>

 </Project>
```

You can create this file using an editor and click View Files o(on the right side) -> Upload in the portal to upload it to your function.

And simply at the top of the function:

```
using SendGrid;
using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;
```

solved my similar problem. 
I have deleted 
     #r "System.Configuration"
     #r "System.Data"

at the top.