# How to add microsoft references for Azure Function use

Tags: c#, function, azure, search

I am trying to add our first Azure Function App, which will read from a queue and update an Azure Search Index.   I wrote everything in a C# dialog app to make sure the data would parse and upload properly.

Apparently when you are running in Azure the following line of code is too much to ask for:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Search;
```

Azure has no idea what that library is, and now I have to stop using the Portal and download Visual Studio 2017 and follow a long list of steps to put this Microsoft supplied reference into my Azure bin folder for Azure Functions?

Really Microsoft?   I just need access to the Search objects and I am done, but the little documentation I can find says I need to spend a few days installing software and setting up FTP somewhere if I want to get there.

Is there a more direct path?

Comment: This is not a programming question, this is pure rant

Comment: I agree with @CamiloTerevinto in that this question contains too much rant. Perhaps you could edit it to describe your problem clearly and make your question stand out. I know it's hard to keep our emotions in check when we find stuff like this and we just want to go and shout it to the world, but consider that StackOverflow might not be the place to do that ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you develop function through the portal then use NuGet package. The package is called [Microsoft.Azure.Search](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Search)

In short, you have to create a project.json file with the required NuGet package references.

[Here is a good explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36411536/how-can-i-use-nuget-packages-in-my-azure-functions) and [here you can find Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#using-nuget-packages).