# Update csproj File Azure Function In portal editor

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, sendgrid, azure-webjobs

I am writing an azure function that needs a NuGet package `Sendgrid`. The only way I found was to update the `.csproj` file.

Now in the View File option, I can't go back to the parent directory, but I can go from the Console. I just need to update the `.csproj` file in the parent directory so that I can update the Nuget packages.

I need to all the work in the provided in the portal editor. I know I can publish the code by any IDE

- [Ref 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#referencing-external-assemblies)
- [Ref 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#referencing-external-assemblies)

Thanks

**UPDATE 1:** [Link to update csproj](https://learn.microsoft.com/mt-mt/azure/azure-functions/install-update-binding-extensions-manual) but the reference to Sendgrid is not established after the link

**UPDATE 2: (ANSWER)** [Link to manually add Nuget Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36411536/how-can-i-use-nuget-packages-in-my-azure-functions) This worked for me. But Update 1 was worth trying

Answer (score 1):

*The only way I found was to update the .csproj file*

To add a NuGet package to an Azure function, you can add it to the project.json file in the portal:

[image]

Then reference it in the .csx file:

[image]

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Have you added the `using` references to the function .csx file? Have you tried what the link you posted suggested, upload an extensions.csproj file?

Comment: Yes, I had already tried the #r with the using but no progress. From the reference, it says to upload the csproj file but its not possible because there is now way to do that. However I have found a way through Kudus, update the csproj file but it didn't either solve the issue

Comment: The Link
https://learn.microsoft.com/mt-mt/azure/azure-functions/install-update-binding-extensions-manual

Comment: _" I had already tried the #r with the using"_ - you can only use `#r` with certain assemblies, NuGet packages have regular `using` statements: updated answer.

Comment: I have also done that but the references are not getting resolved, you please assist how did you bind you `project.json` wih `csproj `

Comment: I don't have a .csproj file, I just write the functions in the portal..

Comment: `csproj` does exists in the parent directory of your directory you are working in or in the parent directory where your csx exists

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184137/discussion-between-jackboys-and-stuartd).