# Azure function: how to upload a function.proj file

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I cannot figure out how to upload a function.proj file.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#referencing-external-assemblies led me to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference#fileupdate

but neither of them have any screenshot showing where the button is.
I searched some other SO post such as this [How can I use NuGet packages in my Azure Functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36411536/how-can-i-use-nuget-packages-in-my-azure-functions)

But my UI is different than the OP maybe the UI has been updated?
[image]

This is the error I am getting,

020-10-07T11:30:14.445 [Error] run.csx(7,23): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'ServiceBus' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Azure' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2020-10-07T11:30:14.489 [Error] run.csx(8,23): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'ServiceBus' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Azure' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2020-10-07T11:30:14.531 [Error] run.csx(9,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Identity' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: After the update in May, the upload button was removed. Now you cannot click the button to upload directly. You can read the answer I posted.

Comment: Hi, Any other doubts? If my answer answered your question, can we end this question now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the UI of function has been changed. This change started in May of this year.

Now there is no upload button right now, we have only two ways:

**1, use kudu to upload the file:**

Go to `https://yourfunctionappname.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`, go to `D:\home\site\wwwroot\yourtriggername>`, then click below button to create the file:

[image]

**2, use linked storage to upload the file:**

When you create the function app on azure, you will based on a storage on azure. You can find all contents of your function app in the storage.

Get the linked storage name:(On my side the linked storage named '0730bowmanwindow'.)

[image]

Go to the storage and go to the file share storage part:

[image]

Click your function app name:

[image]

Then click in site->wwwroot->yourtriggername, use below button to upload file:

[image]

Comment: How do I "Go to the storage"? I tried to click Home -> Storage accounts (is this the right place?), but I don't see my account Name there.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use azure function core tools ( using vs code or event command line ) https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs-code?tabs=csharp , so you can upload your files into the function .

Or in alternative , you can use the blade "app service editor ( Preview ) " on your function app  and from there you will be able to upload files

Hope is useful