# How to publish Azure Function on Azure portal with all its dependencies and NuGet packages

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio, azure-functions

I'm developing an Azure Function using C# and I had to use a NuGet package called NetOffice.

I finished mu function and published it on Azure portal, but when i run it for testing, i get an error that the package i used is not installed.

I want clear and step by step guide to know how to install the package in Azure portal OR how to publish my function with all its packages from Visual Studio.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36411536/how-can-i-use-nuget-packages-in-my-azure-functions

Comment: Plenty of doco on this … https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp?tabs=functionsv2#using-nuget-packages

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, If you have installed the NuGet packages in your Azure function in visual studio and deploy to the Azure portal, it should work fine.

*I have reproduced your requirement by taking a sample Azure function and deployed to Azure portal. It’s working fine as expected and I could see the packages installed.*

[image]

If any package is missing, it might be deployment not happened properly and you can see the required packages used in the local Azure Functions Project in Azure Portal Function App Kudu Site > Debug Console > `C:\home\site\wwwroot\bin>`

[image]

If any NuGet Package or reference assembly is missing, you can upload them here by clicking on `+` Symbol.
Refer to this [article](https://h-savran.blogspot.com/2019/08/adding-nuget-packages-to-azure.html) from savran’s blog for more information.